# Power Bi set WhatIf parameter between variable limits does not work

Tags: parameters, powerbi, slicers

I need to create a set of dynamic input values to perform further calculations.
Let me explain:
Let's say the user select one category in the variable Products, for example Cat01.
Then I need to search for the current price of Cat01 from the CurrentPrice and display that value.
Then the user can suggest a new price for Cat01 and I need to capture this new price and perform further calculations.

My plan is to use CurrentPrice * 0.3 and CurrentPrice * 2 as min and max limits for a WhatIf parameter, then capture the value selected by the user and finally made the calculations.

The problem is the WhatIf parameter does not take into account the limits I'm setting.

The calculus sequence is:
-First I capture the CurrentPrice in a measure, based on user selected Product, with a zero if nothing is selected:

```
CurrentPrice = LOOKUPVALUE(MyTable[CurrentPrice],MyTable[Product], [Product], 0)
```

-Then I created two new measures: maximum and minimum price that I want to offer as modification range to the user for that product:

```
CurPr_min = IF(MyTable[CurrentPrice] > 0, INT(MyTable[CurrentPrice] * 0.3), 0)
```

And

```
CurPr_max = IF(MyTable[CurrentPrice] > 0, INT(MyTable[CurrentPrice] * 2), 0)
```

-Then I created a WhatIf generic parameter:

```
NewPrice = GENERATESERIES(1, 20000, 1)
```

-And I modified the parameter limits:

```
NewPrice = GENERATESERIES(CurPr_min, CurPr_max, 1)
```

But the slicer parameter keeps showing 0 as lower limit and 20000 as upper limit when I select a Product.

It is possible to set the limits for WhatIf parameter from variable's values?

My reasoning for capturing the price modifications is the best way in Power BI?